# Nginx Rewrite rule core PHP + Wordpress | Not able to login to WP-Admin panel

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite, wordpress

I have a static website developed in core PHP (No framework used) and I have also installed a blog using wordpress in a subdirectory under same domain.

```
Like : example.com/blog
```

Since the main site is built using static php files, as per SEO recommendation, I have written a simple rewrite rule to remove .php extension from urls.

So

```
http://example.com/abc.php will rewrite to http://example.com/abc
```

Now coming to actual problem.

When i try to login to http://example.com/blog/wp-admin and put username and password it redirects wp-login.php but due to above rewrite rule it changes to wp-login and causes redirect 404 page not found on main site.

Rewrite rule Nginx vhost- conf is:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    if ($request_uri ~ (.*)\.php$) {
        return 301 $1;
    }

    try_files $uri =404;

    expires off;

    fastcgi_read_timeout 900s;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
```

**I know it may not be the best way to do this** but i have tried almost all the answers on stackexchange for hours and finally get this working using above.

My question is that how can i exclude wp-admin from such redirection? or else someone can suggest any alternate good redirect/rewrite rule to avoid such collision?

**Complete Nginx Config:**

```
server {
    listen 80; # Default listen port
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 permanent;
    }
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root  /home/example.com/public_html/;
    index index.php index.html;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/skpat77-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/skpat77-error.log;
    gzip on; # Turn on gZip
    gzip_static on;
    gzip_comp_level 9;
    gzip_min_length  1400;
    gzip_vary  on;
    gzip_types  text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;


    #error 500 502 503
    error_page 500 502 503 /500x.html;
    location = /500x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if ($request_uri ~ (.*)\.php$) {
            return 301 $1;
        }

        try_files $uri =404;

        expires off;

        fastcgi_read_timeout 900s;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /blog/ {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is your complete nginx configuration?

Comment: @Tero- I have updated Nginx config in question.

Comment: Still not able to find a better solutions for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this configuration:

```
server {
    # Handle redirects to www.example.com
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 http://www.example.com$uri;
}

server {
    listen 80; # Default listen port
    server_name www.example.com;
    root  /home/example.com/public_html/;
    index index.php index.html;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/skpat77-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/skpat77-error.log;
    gzip on; # Turn on gZip
    gzip_static on;
    gzip_comp_level 9;
    gzip_min_length  1400;
    gzip_vary  on;
    gzip_types  text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    # Add .php extension to list of files to go through before trying WP
    try_files $uri $uri.php $uri/ /index.php?$args;


    #error 500 502 503
    error_page 500 502 503 /500x.html;
    location = /500x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if ($request_uri ~ (.*)\.php$) {
            return 301 $1;
        }

        try_files $uri =404;

        expires off;

        fastcgi_read_timeout 900s;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /blog/ {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri.php $uri/ /blog/index.php;
    }
}
```

However, the problem with this approach is that there can be other side-effects. I recommend that you use the raw .php files with the extension, or implement a similar friendly URL system as in Wordpress in your own raw PHP files.

Or even better, implement your own PHP files in WP.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking into this issue myself - in the meantime I have found that I can login using /blog/index.php/wp-admin/ rather than /blog/wp-admin/

This is not intended as a solution, rather a palliative during the reconfig process